# Enviar e-mail com CCO no PHP

Tags: php

Queria saber como enviar e-mail com CCO ("com cópia oculta")?

Código do fórmulário:

```
require('config.php');
$sqlstt = "SELECT * FROM tb_site WHERE id='1'";
$resultstt = mysql_query($sqlstt);        
$rowtt = mysql_fetch_array($resultstt);

$sitename = $rowtt['sitename'];
$supmails = $rowtt['sitepp']; // E-mail Suporte.
$supmail  = ""; // Envio do email.
$bcc      = null;
$nome_remetente = "Email Marketing $sitename";   
$assunto = strtoupper($user).", E-Mail Marketing";
$email_remetente = $supmails;

// Inicio do envio de menságem para o usuário //    

$email_destinatario = $emaills;

// Conteudo do e-mail (voce poderá usar HTML) //
$mensagem = $description;

// Cabeçalho do e-mail. Nao é necessário alterar geralmente...
$cabecalho  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$cabecalho .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$cabecalho .= "From: \"{$nome_remetente}\" <{$email_remetente}>\n";

// Dispara e-mail e retorna status para variável
$status_envio = @mail ($email_destinatario, $assunto, $mensagem, $cabecalho);

if ($status_envio) { // Se mensagem foi enviada pelo servidor...
    echo "Uma menságem foi enviada para o e-mail do usuário!<br />";
} else { // Se mensagem nao foi enviada pelo servidor...
    echo "Nao conseguimos enviar a sua menságem ao usuário!<br />";
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas lhe ajudou? Ou há problemas nelas? Comente informando ao autor qual a duvida em tentar usar a solução proposta. Se alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema, marque-a como correta clicando em ✓

Answer (score 14):

### Forma correta

Para enviar um e-mail Com Cópia Oculta (CCO) ou do inglês Blind Carbon Copy (BCC), basta adicionar no cabeçalho do e-mail
a seguinte instrução

```
$emailoculto = 'teste@gmail.com';
$cabecalho .= "Bcc: {$emailoculto}\r\n";
```

**Atenção:** De acordo com a [documentação da função `mail()` no PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php), os múltiplos cabeçalhos devem ser separado com `CRLF` ou seja `\r\n`:

> Múltiplos cabeçalhos extra devem ser separados com um CRLF (\r\n)

### Forma não tão correta

Você também pode fazer com POG. Essa alternativa consiste em enviar o e-mail duas vezes, a primeira para seus destinatários e uma segunda vez para a cópia oculta:

```
$emailoculto = 'teste@gmail.com';
$status_envio = @mail ($email_destinatario, $assunto, $mensagem, $cabecalho);
if ($status_envio) { // Se mensagem foi enviada pelo servidor...
    echo "Uma menságem foi enviada para o e-mail do usuário!";
    // Envia para o destinatário oculto
    if (!mail($emailoculto, $assunto, $mensagem, $cabecalho))
        echo "!";

    echo "<br />";

} else // Se mensagem não foi enviada pelo servidor...
    echo "Não conseguimos enviar a sua mensagem ao usuário!<br />";
```

### Melhor Forma

Você também pode (ou deve) utilizar a classe [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) para enviar seus e-mails.

Esta é a melhor alternativa para envio de e-mails com PHP, pois você dispõe de vários recursos de uma forma muito simples como: adicionar anexos, múltiplos destinatários, cópias ou **cópias ocultas**.

Além da possibilidade de configurar facilmente o envio por SMTP, pois **alguns servidores não dão suporte a função `mail()`**.

#### Exemplo de uso:

**email.php**

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;
```

**enviar.php**

```
require_once 'email.php'
global $mail;

$mail->From = 'from@example.com'; // DE
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer'; // DE Nome

$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Destinatário
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Nome OPCIONAL

$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information'); // Responder Para

$mail->addCC('cc@example.com'); // CÓPIA

$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com'); // CÓPIA OCULTA

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Adicionar Anexo
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Nome OPCIONAL
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // E-mail no formato HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject'; // TÍTULO
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>'; // Corpo HTML
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients'; // Corpo TEXTO

if($mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso.';
} else {
    echo 'Erro ao tentar enviar mensagem.<br>';
    echo 'Erro: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Utilizando a função [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) é necessário passar essa informação no cabeçalho que é o último argumento,

basta adicionar essa linha:

```
$cabecalho .=   "From: \"{$nome_remetente}\" <{$email_remetente}>\n";
$cabecalho .=   "Bcc: $email_oculto\n";
```

[Bcc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy): é o cópia oculta(blind carbon copy)

[Cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_copy): Email com cópia (carbon copy)

Comment: Está certo. Entretanto, recomendo o uso de uma biblioteca como o Swift Mailer ao invés do uso simples da mail()

Comment: não funcionou, troquei  $email_oculto por $email_destinatario .

Comment: @user7329, o que aconteceu? o email oculto apareceu? deu erro?

Comment: o email oculto apareceu

Comment: @rray estou com o mesmo problema em um cliente, estou usando o `BCC` no *Header* e mesmo assim o email que deveria estar oculto aparece

Comment: @ErlonChaérles, é linux ou windows a hospedagem?

Comment: o problema pode ser o separador de linha `\n`, deveria ser `\r\n`, conforme [apontado pelo Bruno](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68706)

Comment: @rray é linux, era windows, tinha esse problema e passou a ser linux, e mesmo assim não parou o problema

Comment: Descobri o erro, no início do projeto não haveriam cópias ocultas, então não teria nada no cabeçalho, mas com uma alteração passou-se a ter a necessidade de enviar uma cópia oculta em um caso específico. O erro em si era que o *BCC* e o primeiro parâmetro na função mail estavam usando o mesmos email.

Answer (score 4):

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) multiplos "cabeçalhos adicionais" devem ser separados por CRLF (\r\n). Apenas em alguns casos, e como último recurso, deverias fazer como no teu exemplo e separar os cabeçalhos apenas com LF (\n). Isto porque desta forma não estaria de acordo com o RFC 2822.

Assim, e de acordo com a informação do manual da função, o teu exemplo ficaria.:

```
$cabecalho =    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$cabecalho .=   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$cabecalho .=   "From: \"{$nome_remetente}\" <{$email_remetente}>\r\n";
$cabecalho .=   "Bcc: $email_oculto\r\n";
```