# Receber emails via php fora do servidor

Tags: php, servidor, email

Estou desenvolvendo um site com formulário de contato. O *form* é bem simples apenas com nome, *email*, mensagem e assunto.

Eu tenho o site hospedado num servidor, mas preciso que os dados do *form* sejam recebidos num outro *email*, não o que está configurado no serviço de hospedagem.

Eu tentei pela função `mail` do php e não deu certo. Tentei usar a classe `PHPMailer` e algo relacionado com STMP, mas não conheço muito bem essa área, então também não deu certo.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: A única maneira é utilizar envio de e-mail autenticado utilizando classes como PHPMailer. Com a função mail do php não será possível. Veja o seguinte: ao enviar um e-mail em nome de outro servidor, ao chegar no destino será feito o DNS reverso, ou seja, o sistema irá converter o IP do remetente em um domínio que não será o mesmo domínio do e-mail utilizado como remetente (@seu-dominio.com), logo será considerado spam e não chegará a caixa de correio do destinatário.

Comment: Por acaso você está com o site rodando na Locaweb?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25600/enviar-e-mail-com-cco-no-php?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Oi Felipe, sim, na Locaweb. Consegui agora, como o PHPMailer mesmo, estava  configurando ele errado.